# Changing the background-color every 7 refreshes

Tags: php, session

I need to change the `bgcolor` every 7 refreshes but I need to keep the background the same color until the 7th refresh.  I need to save both the current color and refresh counter in the same file.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$a = "count.txt";

$verify = file_get_contents($a);
$visit = $varify;
$newvisit = $visit +1;

$counter = fopen ($a, "w");
fwrite($counter,$newvisit);
fclose($counter);

if($visit %7 == 0){
    $color = "rgb(" . rand(0,255) . "," . rand(0,255) . "," . rand(0,255) . ")";
    $ocolor = fopen($a, "w" );
    fwrite($ocolor, $newvisit.";".$color);
    fclose($ocolor);
}
echo $visit;
?>

<body style="background-color: <?php echo $culoare; ?>">

</body>
```

Comment: use session to save counter and current background color

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use a txt file?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['initial'])){
        $_SESSION['initial']="1";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['initial']+=1;
    }
    $visit=$_SESSION['initial'];
    $visit %7;

    if($visit %7 == 0){
      $_SESSION['code'] = "rgb(" . rand(0,255) . "," . rand(0,255) . "," . rand(0,255) . ")";
    } else if(isset($_SESSION['code'])) {
      $_SESSION['code']=$_SESSION['code'];
    } else {
      $_SESSION['code']="rgb(0,0,0)";
    }
?>
    <body style="background-color: <?php echo $_SESSION['code']; ?>">

    </body>
```

Comment: I don't need a session. I need to save the count and color in the same txt file

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(is_readable('color.txt')) {
   $data = explode('|', file_get_contents('color.txt'));
} else {
   $data = [0,0];
}
$count = $data[0];
$color = $data[1];
if($count %7 == 0) {
    $color = "rgb(" . rand(0,255) . "," . rand(0,255) . "," . rand(0,255) . ")";
}
file_put_contents('color.txt', ++$count.'|'.$color);
?>


<body style="background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>">

</body>
```

Comment: You probably need to init the $_SESSION['color'] somewhere.

Comment: Your example is not working. I need to save the count and color in the same txt file, maybe should I use an array ? I m new on php. thanks

Comment: Why need to store the color or count on a file, he is storing in session variables

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\singlefile.php on line 3

Comment: edited to use a txtfile... i'm still not sure why this is. Since this changes the bg-color for everyone

Comment: Sill not working:Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\final.php on line 8

Warning: file_put_contents(rgb(245,122,39)|rgb(20,32,177)): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\final.php on line 12

Comment: yeah i mixed up the argumentorder on file_put_contents. It works now

Comment: and i need it to be changed every 7 refresh